# utm virtual machine ssh connect drop after few minutes

Tags: virtual-machine, openssh, ssh-tunnel

i use utm to run a x64 vm on m2 macbook, but the ssh connection always drop after few minutes.
some times when i running progrems like gdb, it will drop the connection

```
Linux pwnbox 6.1.0-17-amd64 #1 SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Debian 6.1.69-1 (2023-12-30) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

```
OpenSSH_9.2, OpenSSL 3.0.11 19 Sep 2023
```

when the drop happen, it will not stop the connection process, so i need to kill the process and the reconnect to ssh.

i try to comment out this 2 lines

```
#ClientAliveInterval 0
#ClientAliveCountMax 0
```

but it do not work